# userform sub giving error 13 type mismatch on dynamic combobox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm getting an error code 13 type mismatch in the code here `For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)` but i'm not sure what it is referring to on this piece of code. I have attached the full vba code below.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value

Next i
    
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
 

   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    n = Application.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)
    
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value


Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = ComboBox2.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value


MsgBox ("Data added")

ComboBox1.Value = ""
ComboBox2.Value = ""
TextBox1.Value = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: First step, `Dim i As Long`. Then, are you sure `n` isn't an error? You should check with `IsError`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response BigBen. If I'm being completely honest I'm a bit in the dark with this my knowledge of VBA is pretty basic and I work off trial and error. I have changed to 'Dim I as Long' but still no luck, I have a feeling it 'n' that is providing the error but becuase I don't understand what 'n' is actually referring to I can't amend it.

Comment: I'm guessing that `n` is an error. You can verify by putting `If IsError(n) Then`, `Debug.Print "error"`, `Exit Sub`, `End If`, after `n = Application.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)`.

Comment: If `n` is an error, that means that no match was found in row 1.

Comment: That's sorted it! Legend, thank you very much!